# How to avoid TypeError while iterating rows in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

My situation: 2 dataframes `IndicRef` and `PrescriPresco`.
I want to match each word in `PrescriPresco['label']` with my word database column `IndicRef['Nom_medicament']` using wuzzyfuzzy.

My code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

IndicRef=pd.read_csv(path, sep='|', encoding='utf-8')
PrescriPresco=pd.read_csv(path,sep=',', encoding='utf-8')

print(IndicRef)
print(PrescriPresco)


for index, row in PrescriPresco.iterrows():
    Correspondinglabel= process.extractOne(PrescriPresco['label'], IndicRef['Nom_medicament'], scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
    print(Correspondinglabel)
```

The error I get: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: There are most likely NaN elements in your data. You should filter them out beforehand

Comment: @maxbachmann It did not work. I tried `IndicRef.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True, inplace=True)
PrescriPresco.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True, inplace=True)` and I have the same error.